# best practices with sessions -login

Tags: php, session, authentication

i have a system with a login. Then, the user made the login and he have access to private stuff (personal data).

i need to recognize what user made the login to get his stuff. so, i need something like this: `$nameUser=$_SESSION['u_name']` correct? then i can do the queries like that :

`Select photo*from tablePhotos where name= $nameUser`.

The code that i have is appropriated, or it has problems of Security?
It is indicated generate a session_id for each session?makes sense? what is the "rule"?

I don't have much experience with sessions...

```
 <?php
    session_start();

    if(empty($_SESSION['u_name']))
    header("Location:index.php");   

    if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
        session_destroy();
        header("Location:emprego.php");
    }

    $name = $_SESSION['u_name'];
    echo $name ;

    echo "<a href='secure.php?logout'><b>Logout<b></a>";

    ?>
```

Comment: Well, to be honest your user associated data should be associated by ID, so instead of storing the full username you instead store an integer that's a lot easier on your table size, and if indexed properly provides quicker lookups.

Comment: the u_name is the email. i think that is more easily check the email and password in the db when the user made the login, and then, store the email (that is unique for each user) in the session.

Comment: In generally with logins you use the email and password to do the lookup required for getting the user id. Then you use the user id to do lookups on user associated data for the reasons I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: i will follow your advice. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you always sanitize your data and use queries like

```
"Select * from tablePhotos where name= '" . mysql_real_escape_string($nameUser) . "'"
```

everything is fine

Comment: i will use mysqli, the query example is just to explanation purpose :)

Comment: @user455318: use prepared statements in mysqli then and everything will be fine

Comment: the session_id() made any sense in this case?

Comment: @user455318: in what context? Any variable should be bind'ed into prepared statement. If you use preparend statements and bind variables into them - you're just fine.